# Import CSV in Datagrip

Tags: mysql, json, csv, datagrip

I'm having some trouble importing a CSV file with over 40 000 records. The problem that the table I'm importing has several relationships and when the table tries to import the records there are records in the relationships tables that don't have these records so it fails creating the records (atleast that's my guess). Note that the relationship is 0 to many.

My table structure that comes in the CSV looks like this:

```
adult,belongs_to_collection,budget,genres,homepage,id,imdb_id,original_language,original_title,overview,popularity,poster_path,production_companies,production_countries,release_date,revenue,runtime,spoken_languages,status,tagline,title,video,vote_average,vote_count
```

One record looks like this:

```
False,"{'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', 'poster_path': '/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg'}",30000000,"[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story,862,tt0114709,en,Toy Story,"Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his room until Andy's birthday brings Buzz Lightyear onto the scene. Afraid of losing his place in Andy's heart, Woody plots against Buzz. But when circumstances separate Buzz and Woody from their owner, the duo eventually learns to put aside their differences.",21.946943,/rhIRbceoE9lR4veEXuwCC2wARtG.jpg,"[{'name': 'Pixar Animation Studios', 'id': 3}]","[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",1995-10-30,373554033,81.0,"[{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}]",Released,,Toy Story,False,7.7,5415
```

So I did recreate the relationship table "belongs_to_collection", "genres", "production_companies", "production_countries" and "spoken_languages"

When I use the Datagrip wizard I create the foreign keys and stuff but when I run I get these kind of errors:

```
2:8: conversion failed: "{'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', 'poster_path': '/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg'}" to int
```

Comment: It looks like you trying to insert 'json' value into field of type 'int'. What is the type of "belongs_to_collection" field in target table? Shouldn't be there only '10194' value instead of entire record?

Comment: Well the problem is that the id 10194 doesn't exist yet and I would like to insert that value in the table "Collection" before adding the record. And for that I'm working on an PHP script that adds all the values that don't exist yet to each table. The question is how do I add the id of the JSON to the belongs_to_collection field. If there is way to do it with DataGrip it would be awesome if not I'll probably just write a script that does that.